# auto_inline - inadequate documentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I want to disable inlining for a particular function. What the compiler does for everything else should be as specified in the project properties. I found a page on a forum which suggested the following:

```
#pragma auto_inline(off)
void func()
{
}
#pragma auto_inline()
```

The author suggested that calling auto_inline() with no arguments will set the compiler to revert to doing whatever the default action was before the call to auto_inline(off). Can anyone confirm that this works for visual studio 2008? I ask because the VS2008 documentation makes no mention at all of what happens if you call this function with no arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__declspec(noinline) void func()
{
}
```